# How do you get the right shape on trim-to-fit insoles?

Tags: hiking, shoes, footwear

My hiking shoes starting having problems with the insoles, so I got replacements.  However the replacements I have are "Trim to fit."

How do I get the proper shape so that I don't end up with any misaligned or rough edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only technique I use is to take out the old ones, draw round them with a sharpie and then cut out to the inside of that line.

This works very well, and trimming to make sure the line is just removed gives an accurate measure.